# Spring Rest Docs json request and response formatting

Tags: json, spring-restdocs

The resulting json when using the  `Preprocessors` `prettyPrint()` is as follows:

```
{
  "testId" : "message-1",
  "testType" : "TYPE",
  "nestedList" : [ {
    "nestedTestId" : 5,
    "nestedTestCode" : 2,
    "anotherNestedList" : [ {
      "anotherNestedFirst" : [ {
        "anotherId" : 1,
        "anotherValue" : "VALUE_1",
        "anotherDescription" : null
      }, {
        "anotherId" : 2,
        "anotherValue" : "VALUE_2",
        "anotherDescription" : "DESCRIPTION"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I want it to look like this:

> braces are newline with slightly (2-space) indented lists as formatted by most online json formatter.

```
{
  "testId": "message-1",
  "testType": "TYPE",
  "nestedList": [
    {
      "nestedTestId": 5,
      "nestedTestCode": 2,
      "anotherNestedList": [
        {
          "anotherNestedFirst": [
            {
              "anotherId": 1,
              "anotherValue": "VALUE_1",
              "anotherDescription": null
            },
            {
              "anotherId": 2,
              "anotherValue": "VALUE_2",
              "anotherDescription": "DESCRIPTION"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried with `Preprocessors` `replacePattern` and other means with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring REST Docs uses Jackson in its default configuration to pretty print JSON requests and responses. You can customise this behaviour by writing your own [`ContentModifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/restdocs/operation/preprocess/ContentModifier.html) with customized pretty printing behaviour and creating a pre-processor that uses it:

```
OperationPreprocessor prettyPrint = new ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor((content, contentType) -> {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .withArrayIndenter(DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE);
    try {
        return objectMapper.writer(prettyPrinter).writeValueAsBytes(objectMapper.readTree(content));
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
         return content;
    }
});
```

The key thing in the above is configuring the array indenter to use linefeeds rather than the default which is spaces.

You can then use `prettyPrint` when documenting an operation:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/example")).andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(document("example", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint)));
```